# initializing multi dimensional arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Im trying to assign specific dynamic values to a multi dimensional array in java. These are the 2 steps which im trying as a work around. Is there an easy direct way.

Im trying to use this code

```
            while (recrdcntrx<numberofrecords)
            {
                mobilephonerecords[recrdcntrx][recrdcntrx][recrdcntrx][recrdcntrx]= {mobilenumbercntrx,unsortedmobilenumbers[mobilenumbercntrx],arraystart[mobilenumbercntrx],arrayend[mobilenumbercntrx]};
                mobilenumbercntrx=mobilenumbercntrx+1;
                recrdcntrx=recrdcntrx+1;
            }
```

but it does not work. So Im trying a workaround.

A. Initialization

```
long mobilephonerecords[][][][]= new long[100][100][100][100];

for (long[][][] row: mobilephonerecords) {
    for (long[][] innerRow: row) {
        for (long[] innerInnerRow: innerRow) {
            Arrays.fill(innerInnerRow, 0);
        }
    }
};
```

I found out the way to initialize them but when i try the next step its throwing a compile time error - 'Array constants can only be used in initializers'

We have to assign these dynamic values - `arrcntr1, unsortedmobilenumbers[arrcntr1],arraystart[arrcntr1],arrayend[arrcntr1]`

```
    int xcntr=0;
        int arrcntr1=0;
        long temp1=0;

        int arrcntr2=0;
        long temp2=0;

        int arrcntr3=0;
        long temp3=0;

        int arrcntr4=0;
        long temp4=0;

        while(xcntr<recrdcntr)
        {
            temp1=arrayend[arrcntr1];
            mobilephonerecords[0][0][0][arrcntr1] = temp1;
            arrcntr1=arrcntr1+1;
            xcntr=xcntr+1;

        }

    int ycntr=0;

        while(ycntr<recrdcntr)
        {
            temp2=arraystart[arrcntr2];
            mobilephonerecords[0][0][arrcntr2][0] = temp2;
            arrcntr2=arrcntr2+1;
            ycntr=ycntr+1;

        }

        int zcntr=0;

        while(zcntr<recrdcntr)
        {
            temp3=unsortedmobilenumbers[arrcntr3];
            mobilephonerecords[0][arrcntr3][0][0] = temp3;
            arrcntr3=arrcntr3+1;
            zcntr=zcntr+1;

        }


            int icntr=0;

            while(icntr<recrdcntr)
            {
                temp4=icntr;
                mobilephonerecords[arrcntr4][0][0][0] = temp4;
                arrcntr4=arrcntr4+1;
                icntr=icntr+1;

            }
```

1. I tried the workaround but the numbers are not getting assigned -
   3.
   i tried the workaround but the numbers are not getting assigned to the mobilephonerecords 4d array.

   ```
   while (recrdcntrx<numberofrecords)
   {
       System.out.println("mobilephonerecords[][][][] -"+mobilephonerecords[recrdcntrx][recrdcntrx][recrdcntrx][recrdcntrx]);
       mobilenumbercntrx=mobilenumbercntrx+1;
       recrdcntrx=recrdcntrx+1;
   }

   recrdcntrx=0;
   while (recrdcntrx<numberofrecords)
   {
       System.out.println("print mobilephonerecords as array-"+mobilephonerecords);
       mobilenumbercntrx=mobilenumbercntrx+1;
       recrdcntrx=recrdcntrx+1;
   }
   ```

   4. Output

   mobilephonerecords[][][][] -0
   mobilephonerecords[][][][] -0
   print mobilephonerecords as array-[[[[J@55f96302
   print mobilephonerecords as array-[[[[J@55f96302

Comment: Side note: it would be more idiomatic to use a `for`-loop for a loop with a counter, this limits the scope of the counter to the body of the loop.

Comment: What is "dynamic values" and what error do you get? I think you need to read up on [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Side note 2: there is also the post-increment operator, which could be used to write the increments with less repetition: `arrcntr1=arrcntr1+1;` could be written as `arrcntr1++;`

Comment: Your error message is 'Array constants can only be used in initializers' but you're not using array constants in any of the code you've shown us. The error must be somewhere else. Check the line number reported in the error message.

Comment: Basically, i want to use this code -

          while (recrdcntr<numberofrecords)
          {
           mobilephonerecords[recrdcntr][recrdcntr][recrdcntr][recrdcntr]= {mobilenumbercntr,unsortedmobilenumbers[mobilenumbercntr],arraystart[mobilenumbercntr],arrayend[mobilenumbercntr]};
           mobilenumbercntr=mobilenumbercntr+1;
           recrdcntr=recrdcntr+1;
          }
but im getting the error Array constants cannot be used as initializers...

Comment: `mobilephonerecords[recrdcntrx][recrdcntrx][recrdcntrx][recrdcntrx]` is not an array, it is a `long`. Why are you trying to assign an array to that position?

Comment: ok. thanks, im trying the work around...

Comment: I have edited the question and added the output but the values are not getting assigned to the array.

Answer (score 1):

`new long[100][100][100][100]` will initialize the array with default `long` value `0`. You can see it by checking random index in the array:

```
long[][][][] arr = new long[100][100][100][100];
System.out.println(arr[30][21][33][17]); // 0
```

There is no need to use `Arrays.fill()` to initialize the array yourself, as per [JLS 4.12.5. Initial Values of Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5):

> Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is initialized with a default value when it is created (§15.9, §15.10):

Comment: hmmm .... ok but the second step is more important. can you please give your valuable comments on it.

Comment: @saifahmed your second step is very unclear, please update the question to explain what are you doing.

Comment: I have edited the question. please check.